# iOS - UICollectionView in UITableViewCell, problems when handling touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in every `UITableViewCell` of my `UITableView`.
The program should perform a segue there is a click on the `UITableViewCell` but the cell is clickable just out of the `UICollectionView`.

It is clickable just in the red portions.

[image: screenshot]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try this : http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable user interaction in each collection view:

In your storyboard uncheck here:

[image]

Or in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    cell.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: It works perfectly but doing it directly on the collectionView and not on each collectionViewCell. In any case, thank you!!

Comment: Yep, you are right, my mistake! I updated my answer.

Comment: But then you lose the horizontal scrolling. any suggestions on how to have both?